# GoogleDrive FilesResource.UpdateMediaUpload doesn't report progress, only start/finish

Tags: google-drive-api

I have the following code set up to display progress for uploading files:

```
FilesResource.UpdateMediaUpload updateRequest = service.Files.Update(myFile, fileID, stream, myFile.MimeType);
updateRequest.ProgressChanged += (s) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Progress Update");
                if (m_oWorker.IsBusy)
                {
                    int percent = (int)(100 * ((Double)s.BytesSent / maxLength));
                    Console.WriteLine("Sending Bytes: " + s.BytesSent.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine("Sending Bytes percent: " + percent.ToString());
                    m_oWorker.ReportProgress(percent);
                }
            };
            updateRequest.Upload();
```

Which results in this:

```
Progress Update
Sending Bytes: 0
Sending Bytes percent: 0

Progress Update
Sending Bytes: 7199570
Sending Bytes percent: 100
```

The work is being done in a background worker thread but that shouldn't affect it I thought?

Is there something I'm not doing right here?

Answer (score 0):

To quote the documentation for [media upload in the .NET client library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/media_upload):

> Notification of progress changed will be invoked when the upload was started, on each upload chunk, and on success or failure.

Regarding chunk size:

> The default chunk size is 10MB, but you can change it by setting the ChunkSize property on the request to any multiple of 256KB.